# Unexpected compiler warning for "<T extends ...>" return type

Tags: java, generics, javac

When I compile the following Java code (using Oracle JDK 1.7.0_25):

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    interface Example {

        <T extends Example> T init();
    }

    static class ExampleImpl implements Example {

        @Override
        public ExampleImpl init() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

I get a warning:

```
StackOverflowQuestion.java:11: warning: [unchecked] init()
  in ExampleImpl implements <T>init() in Example
        public ExampleImpl init() {
                           ^
  return type requires unchecked conversion from ExampleImpl to T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Example declared in method <T>init()
```

I can't understand why it says "return type requires unchecked conversion" as the class implements `Example` so as far as I can see it's a valid return type.

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic method in `Example` is supposed to work where `T` can be any type extending `Example`, but you have tried to implement it in `ExampleImpl` in such a way that it always returns an `ExampleImpl`. This  may be ok if `ExampleImpl` is the only class implementing `Example`, but if there are others you can get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

In the following example, we instantiate a new `ExampleImpl`, cast it to the base interface and then call the generic method `init()` with `T` equal to `ExampleImpl2`. This is supposed to return an `ExampleImpl2`, but since you returned `this`, it throws a `ClassCastException`. This is why your code must generate a warning.

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    interface Example {

        <T extends Example> T init();
    }

    static class ExampleImpl implements Example {

        @Override
        public ExampleImpl init() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    static class ExampleImpl2 implements Example {

        @Override
        public <T extends Example> T init() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExampleImpl2 e2 = ((Example) new ExampleImpl()).<ExampleImpl2>init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My java's a little rusty, but can't you return a derived class in an overridden method?

public class StackOverflowQuestion {

```
interface Example {

    Example init();
}

static class ExampleImpl implements Example {

    @Override
    public ExampleImpl init() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: (apologies for code formatting - basically impossible on mobile)

Comment: This answers my *real* question (how to get the behavior I want). I'll upvote but leave pbabcdefp's as the accepted answer as it answers the question I posed.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't meet my real need as I want type-safe parameters too. E.g. `class EuclideanVector implements Vector<EuclideanVector>` and a method `EuclideanVector plus(EuclideanVector vector)`

Comment: @aetheria: If the aim of this is to produce an interface you would ever use as a variable type (polymorphically), then you can't have it be generic. But as you correctly surmise, your use case does not work polymorphically. Out of interest, what is a "euclidian vector"? Do you mean Cartesian?